# rails redirect_to different subdomain, controller, and params

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, subdomain

If a user tries to go to a specific page on a mobile device (say: myapp.com/foo) I want to redirect them to a different page on the mobile site with parameters (in this case: m.myapp.com/bar?param1=foo).

I've figured out how to redirect to a different page with parameters (like myapp.com/bar?param1=foo), but I cannot figure out how to redirect to another subdomain without providing the whole string as in: `redirect_to "m.myapp.com/bar?param1=foo"`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of Rails you are using, you can accomplish this via:

```
redirect_to some_url(subdomain: 'some_subdomain', some_param: 'foo')
```

The URL helpers accept a `subdomain` argument--as of Rails 3, I think.